# Objective-c Json Parsing Empty Array Error or Bug?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, xcode

When i parsing json with tableview everything good when have json items but if not load json items and when i clicked back button gives me this error.

```
erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
```

I think json don't load when i clicked fastly back button and gives this error my table view codes under.

```
    @interface MasterViewController ()

    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger currentPage;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger totalPages;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger totalItems;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger maxPages;

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *activePhotos;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *staticDataSource;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;


    @end


            - (void)viewDidLoad
            {
                [super viewDidLoad];

                self.activePhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                self.staticDataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


            }


            #pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return  self.activePhotos.count;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (indexPath.row == [self.activePhotos count]) {
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LoadingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    } else {
        NSDictionary *photoItem = self.activePhotos[indexPath.row];
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.textLabel.text = [photoItem objectForKey:@"name"];
        if (![[photoItem objectForKey:@"description"] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [photoItem objectForKey:@"description"];
        }


    }


    return cell;
}



- (void)loadPhotos:(NSInteger)page
{



    NSString *userismim =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userisim"];


    NSArray* words = [userismim componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet :[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString* nospacestring = [words componentsJoinedByString:@""];


    NSLog(@"%@",nospacestring);


    NSString *apiURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bla.com/server/table.php?user=%@",nospacestring];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiURL]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {

                if (!error) {

                    NSError *jsonError = nil;
                    NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

                    NSLog(@"%@",jsonObject);

                    [self.staticDataSource addObjectsFromArray:[jsonObject objectForKey:@"photos"]];

                    self.currentPage = [[jsonObject objectForKey:@"current_page"] integerValue];
                    self.totalPages  = [[jsonObject objectForKey:@"total_pages"] integerValue];
                    self.totalItems  = [[jsonObject objectForKey:@"total_items"] integerValue];

                    self.activePhotos = self.staticDataSource;

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    });
                }
            }] resume];
}
```

Thanks for everything . i need your help.

Comment: Where is `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: @TimurBernikowich added bottom

Comment: You have many problems in your code as I can see. First of all, your NSURLSessionTask has strong pointer to your ViewController. Thats why it's still reloads when you go back.

Comment: Add breakpoint on line `NSDictionary *photoItem = self.activePhotos[indexPath.row];` and check why we go there.

Comment: added interface codes top

Comment: @TimurBernikowich gives with breakpoint that  " cell UITableViewCell * nil 0x00000000 "

Comment: What about `self.activePhotos`? Does it have any objects?

Comment: Normally if i wait when 2-4 seconds everything good parsing them but i fastly click back button gives this error and self.activePhotos on that time 0

Comment: any idea ? I'm trying everything but still nothing..

Comment: and what is `nodeCount` and `indexPath.row`?

Comment: @TimurBernikowich i did clear codes dude look at codes

Comment: Does it still crash? Just add "All Exception Breakpoint" and try to determine why you get there and why it crash.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich added all breakpoints and crash here :          NSDictionary *photoItem = self.activePhotos[indexPath.row];  and values  page 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing activity indicator which will keep rotating till `json` loads.

If you are pressing back button before `json` loads, what happens is app tries to allocate empty reference to array which is not possible, so it throws an error.

To avoid this, you can stop `userInteraction` once request goes, and enable only after getting success or failure response.

To disable interaction, add

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplicaton] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]
```

after

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
```

And to enable again, add :

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplicaton] endIgnoringInteractionEvents]
```

before

```
if (!error) {
```

This will solve your issue I hope.

Comment: When i adding gives me  "No known class method for selector 'sharedApplicaton'" error

Comment: Can you try this. All aplication has an instance of UIApplication.[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

Comment: I Added them  ;    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiURL]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {
                
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
                if (!error) {
 and gives same error

Comment: Can you please try this once : [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]

Comment: gives error here NSDictionary *photoItem = self.activePhotos[indexPath.row];

Comment: when trying add it  gives  No known instance method for selector 'beginIgnoringInteractionEvents'

Comment: activePhotos is an array. accessing that way is wrong I think.  NSDictionary *photoItem =(NSDictionary*) [self.activePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: activePhotos NSMutableArray look at top side in codes